throwing error when using html_entity_decode in smarty 5
When i use the html_entity_decode in smarty version 5, it throwing fatal error unknown modifier
Error

Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template unknown modifier 'html_entity_decode'

Code
{$latestnewsta.fld_news_title|html_entity_decode|strip_tags:true|truncate:200}


Note
smarty version 5, php 8.2

Is there something unclear about the error? html_entity_decode is not a valid modifier. Did you mean unescape?

If these people knew PHP instead of just frameworks and libraries, they would be able to help themselves.

Maybe you must register html_entity_decode as a modifier before you can use it in your template: $smarty->registerPlugin('modifier', 'html_entity_decode', 'html_entity_decode');
